# Language to CFG

Tags: context-free-grammar

I have the following exercise. I have to create a CFG from the following language:

```
M = {a^m b^n| 2m > n > m}
```

Currently I have:

```
S -> aaSbbb

A -> aaA

B -> bbbB
```

Im not sure if this is correct. Also how do I apply limit so that `2m > n` still holds instead of just `n > m` where `n` can just be any number as long as it is bigger than `m`

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What's a CFG???

Comment: context free grammar @Teddy38

Answer (score 1):

The $A$ and $B$ rules would make it possible to increase either $m$ or $n$ without increasing the other. For example, if you had a string with an $A$ in it, then rule $A \to aaA$ would let you make as many '$a$'s as you wanted without regard to how many '$b$'s get produced by any other applications of the rules.

On the other hand I don't see how either of the rules for $A$ or $B$ could ever get invoked. (You start with just $S$, right?)

In order to prevent runaway production of either '$a$'s or '$b$'s,
there is a very limited choice of where in the string you can allow a rule to be invoked that produces either '$a$'s or '$b$'s.

Below is a graph that shows how many '$a$'s a string has
(the number on the bottom row) and
how many '$b$'s it has (the number in the left column).
For each combination of '$a$'s and '$b$'s, there is a $*$ if the string
is a member of your language.
I have only taken this up to $m=5$ but you can extend the table to the
right and upward.

\begin{matrix}
9 & & & &* \\
8 & & & &* \\
7 & & &*&*\\
6 & & &*&*\\
5 & &*&*\\
4 & &*\\
3 &*\\
  &2&3&4&5
\end{matrix}

You have identified a rule $S \to aaSbbb$
that produces the shortest possible string in the language--
or at least it *almost* does that, because there's still an $S$
in that string, and you have no way to eliminate $S$.
All you can do is keep on applying that rule and producing more
'$a$'s and '$b$'s with a new $S$ in the middle.

At some point you need a rule with $S$ on the left and *without* $S$ on the right. Also, you need at least one rule that has only '$a$'s and '$b$'s
on the right (possibly the empty string).
Otherwise you'll never reach a point where you have a string with
only '$a$'s and '$b$'s in it and can stop applying rules.
Of course, these could be the same rule.

So you want to be able to get to the count $m=2,n=3$ *and stop there.*
You also want to be able to get to any of the other strings represented
in the graph (and stop there).

You have a couple of choices about how to do this.
You can make sure you produce at least two '$a$'s and three '$b$'s,
and then have additional rules that let you insert additional
'$a$'s and '$b$'s (while staying inside the "legal" area of the graph)
or stopping.
Or you could produce all the "additional" '$a$'s and '$b$'s *first*
and then insert $aabbb$ in the middle.
Or you could allow some combination of the two procedures, but it seems
to me a simpler set of rules is better.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to work. can you check s -> aaTbbb, T -> aTKb | epsilon, K -> b | epsilon

Comment: That looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a production for the upper bound by

$U\rightarrow ab^2 | aUb^2$

Then your valid strings are

$S \rightarrow aUb | aSb$

To see that this generates the grammar note that if $S = a^mb^{m+k}$ where $0\lt k\lt m$ then $S = a^{m-k}a^kb^{2k}b^{m-k}$.